# Return corresponding variable for max value in grouped dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I am looking to return the corresponding value for a max value for each group in a dataframe in R. Searching I can only find solutions for python and excel.

I seem to get the right answers but in a strange format:

Example:

```
set.seed(423)
df = data.frame(week = c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 7), rep(3, 7)), 
                day = c(1:7, 1:7, 1:7), 
                value = runif(21))
    df
   week day      value
1     1   1 0.89368600
2     1   2 0.63863225
3     1   3 0.19254541
4     1   4 0.57557113
5     1   5 0.78458928
6     1   6 0.55080956
7     1   7 0.59388856
8     2   1 0.02040073
9     2   2 0.17663162
10    2   3 0.33647923
11    2   4 0.53304330
12    2   5 0.22939499
13    2   6 0.43232959
14    2   7 0.71889969
15    3   1 0.97318020
16    3   2 0.20320008
17    3   3 0.58991593
18    3   4 0.88450876
19    3   5 0.61154896
20    3   6 0.68123761
21    3   7 0.48162899

library('dplyr')

group_by(df, week) %>%
  summarize(max.day = .[which(value == max(value, na.rm = T)), 'day'])

   week max.day$    NA    NA
  <dbl>    <int> <int> <int>
1     1        1     7     1
2     2       NA    NA    NA
3     3       NA    NA    NA
```

The value for max.day (1, 7, 1) appear correct, as can be seen if you match the values from this code to the original df:

```
group_by(df, week) %>%
  summarise(value = max(value))

   week value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0.894
2     2 0.719
3     3 0.973
```

But what I want (and what I expected from the code) is a table that looks as follows:

```
  week max.day
1    1       1
2    2       7
3    3       1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, will this code work if i have a large dataset in which the max value might repeat for certain groups. Essentially will my `.[which(value == max(value, na.rm = T)), 'day']` be applied group-wise, or is this just looking at the entire vector?

Comment: setNames(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$week),
                                 
                                 function(x){x[which.max(x$value),c("week", "day")]})),
         
         c("week", "max_day"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `which.max`. If there are ties for `max` 'value' i.e. more than one `max` value for each 'week', then `which.max` returns the index of the first `max` 'value', use that to subset the corresponding 'day'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(week) %>% 
   summarise(max.day = day[which.max(value)])
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   week max.day
#  <int>   <int>
#1     1       1
#2     2       7
#3     3       1
```

With `==`, there is the possibility of matching multiple elements if there are ties and `summarise` can return only single row/group resulting in conflict of interest and ultimately error

---

Another option is to either `filter` or `slice` the rows if the intention is to return the row

```
df %>%
   group_by(week) %>%
   slice(which.max(value)) %>%
   select(week, max.day = day)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), day = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L), value = c(0.893686, 0.63863225, 0.19254541, 0.57557113, 
0.78458928, 0.55080956, 0.59388856, 0.02040073, 0.17663162, 0.33647923, 
0.5330433, 0.22939499, 0.43232959, 0.71889969, 0.9731802, 0.20320008, 
0.58991593, 0.88450876, 0.61154896, 0.68123761, 0.48162899)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"))
```

Comment: That works. Thanks very much.